# Method to return a generic type when passing in a delegate as a parameter

Tags: c#, generics, types, func

I'm trying to 'genericize' some code we have spattered around our system.

I want to:

1. return a generic type,
2. pass in some kind of delegate containing the method to be called.

I'm pretty new to generics so any help appreciated.

Below is where my finger in the air is(!)

```
public static T ReturnSingleObject<T>(Func<string, int, T> dynamicSignature)
    {
        T returnValue;
        ServiceReference wCFService;
        try
        {
            wCFService = new BusinessServiceClient();

            returnValue = dynamicSignature();

            //returnValue = wCFService.AMETHOD(PARAM1, PARAM2);
            return returnValue;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (wCFService != null) wCFService.Abort();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (wCFService != null) wCFService.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A couple of details: instead of try ... finally you'd be better with a using (var WCFService = new BusinessServiceClient()) { your code } 
In the call to dynamicSignature you're missing the string and int parameters.

Comment: I want to dynamically pass any method for calling on wCFService and return the result.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing a couple parameters for your dynamicSignature function, so you'll need to add those.  Also, you might move your return statement to the bottom, out of the try block, and initialize your return value to the default value:

```
T returnValue = default(T);
...
try
{
   ...
   returnValue = dynamicSignature(somestring, someint);
   ...
}
...

return returnValue;
```